# Trying to remove an element with data-value equal to a previously created variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on a "trash" button I want to delete the message block. There are multiple message blocks but they all have unique `data-values`. The `id` of the targeted block I want to delete is stored in the `data-value` of `.send-message-button`.

I tried making a variable that I could pass onto the targeted `.messageblock` element. I checked with an `alert` to see if the variable gets the proper number, which it does. However when I `alert` the whole thing, it gives `[object object]` (without the `.remove`, of course).

How can I do this?

```
var trashid = $(".send-message-button").attr("data-value");
$('.message-block').attr("data-value", trashid).remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve an element using the value of one of its attributes you need to use the attribute selector, not the setter of the `attr()` method.

There's two main ways to do this. Firstly if the `data` attribute is present in the DOM then you can use an attribute selector:

```
var trashid = $(".send-message-button").data('value');
$('.message-block[data-value="' + trashid + '"]').remove();
```

Alternatively if the `data` attribute is held in jQuery's cache (as will be the case if you use `data()` as a getter/setter, as you should be) then you can use `filter()` instead:

```
var trashid = $(".send-message-button").data('value');
$('.message-block').filter((i, e) => $(e).data('value') === trashid).remove();
```

Comment: huh, all methods seemed to work... but why should I be using the .data() instead of the .attr("data-value") if they both work fine?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7262427/519413) explains it better than I ever could, but the short answer is performance.

Comment: thanks for the answer and link. something i found interesting, though I know its not part of the question. When I remove one block, it works perfectly. However, when I try to remove more than one, it stops working after the first one. However there is an ajax request that follows the click function. Even though it doesnt appear to be removed. It is in the server. Have any idea why its not removing the other divs?

Comment: I know you suggest not to use the `.attr("data-value")` approach, but when swapping out your `.data('value')` with `.attr("data-value")` in each location, for both suggestions, it started to work. not exactly sure why, or if it is bad, but I will use this method for now